# How to convert PHP object to JSON fromat for OpenAPI 3

Tags: php, json, validation, openapi

I'm currently working on API for PHP project using `OpenAPI 3.0.2`. 
The problem is that I've got the nested php array according to which I want to describe an `OpenAPI` Schema and send this data as JSON inside POST request body for testing.

**Here is the PHP data I want to convert to JSON:**

```
    [[
        'question'    => 'Do you have an active mobile money account?'
        'answers'     => [
            [
                'label'  => 'A.',
                'text'   => 'Yes',
                'custom' => false,
                'value'  => 'yes',
            ],
            [
                'label'  => 'B.',
                'text'   => 'No',
                'custom' => false,
                'value'  => 'no',
            ]
        ],
    ],...]
```

**And here is a JSON which I've already tried to make, but it didn't match the data object (server's validation failed)**

**openapi.json**

```
"example":{
    "survey": [
                {
                  "question": "mobile money account",
                  "answers": [
                    [[{"label":"A."},{"text": "Yes"},{"custom": false},{"value":"yes"}]]
                  ]
                },
     ...
}
```

**NOTE!** The validation fails only on `"answers"` property!

**EDITED:**
using `json_decode($arr,true)` gives me the following:

```
"answers": [
                {
                  "label": "A.",
                  "text": "Yes",
                  "custom": false,
                  "value": "yes"
                },
                {
                  "label": "B.",
                  "text": "No",
                  "custom": false,
                  "value": "no"
                }
              ]
```

But the server still responds with an error that "answers" are invalid

Comment: Do you mean `json_encode($theArray)`

Comment: have you tried json_encode($phparray, true);  ?

Comment: @RiggsFolly I've tested It right now (only answers property) and it returns a really strange output

Comment: Show us the output (edit your question) and show us what is wrong with it

Comment: @RiggsFolly done

Comment: Show the `json_encode()` you used. You didnt use `json_encode($theArray, true)` I hope as that is the format of a `json_decode()`

Comment: I think OP is confusing many things here, and there must be code affecting the output and behaviour which is not shown in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Each object in JSON corresponds to a separate associative array (or PHP object, but we're going to talk about arrays here).

So to get such JSON `"answer"` attribute's value:

```
[
     [[{"label":"A."},{"text": "Yes"},{"custom": false},{"value":"yes"}]]
]
```

We need an "array of arrays of arrays of associative arrays".

So in PHP it should be:

```
 [[[
    ["label" => "A."],
    ["text" => "Yes"],
    ["custom" => false],
    ["value" => "yes"]
]]]
```

**Note**
For me it looks like too many nesting in the expected structure, but whatever - this is what you said you want.

Comment: Sorry but you did the backward conversion. I can not modify PHP array because It was committed by another developed. I need to retrieve a JSON representation but I can not understand what is going wrong here

Comment: I don't get it. You have a PHP array and want to get a JSON representation of it, that has a specific structure. Is that correct? If so, you need to prepare suitable PHP array - it may be a copy of that "other developer commited" (whatever it means) if you cannot "touch it")) - and pass to `json_encode`. That's all.  What exactly can't you understand?

Comment: Of course you can transform any PHP array to whatever you like before outputting it in JSON. I think Jakub is right with the nesting, just came to the same conclusion. I might delete my answer as yours is about the same...

Answer (score 0):

The stuff you show us as "output of json_encode" is not the real output of json_encode. It would never show you an associative array because it does not exist in JSON. It would never give you something like `[ 'label' => 'A.',`.

> I fed the answers to json_encode and here is what I've got:
>
> "'answers'     => [
>               [
>                   'label'  => 'A.',
>                   'text'   => 'Less than 500 UGX',
>                   'custom' => false,
>                   'value'  => '< 500 UGX',
>               ]] "

This is **wrong**. It's not the output of json_encode. See my code below.

I think the problem is in the dimensions of `answers`. You array seems too deep:

`"answers": [
                    [[`

Notice 3 opening array brackets?

---

```
$x = [[
        'question'    => 'Do you have an active mobile money account?',
        'answers'     => [
            [
                'label'  => 'A.',
                'text'   => 'Yes',
                'custom' => false,
                'value'  => 'yes',
            ],
            [
                'label'  => 'B.',
                'text'   => 'No',
                'custom' => false,
                'value'  => 'no',
            ]
        ]
]];

echo json_encode($x, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

// Output:

[
    {
        "question": "Do you have an active mobile money account?",
        "answers": [
            {
                "label": "A.",
                "text": "Yes",
                "custom": false,
                "value": "yes"
            },
            {
                "label": "B.",
                "text": "No",
                "custom": false,
                "value": "no"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Answer (score -1):

Show your full php array data. If it is like this -

```
$d =  [[
    'question'    => 'Do you have an active mobile money account?',
    'answers'     => [
        [
            'label'  => 'A.',
            'text'   => 'Yes',
            'custom' => false,
            'value'  => 'yes',
        ],
        [
            'label'  => 'B.',
            'text'   => 'No',
            'custom' => false,
            'value'  => 'no',
        ]
    ],
],

];
```

Then you need to use json_encode($d,true);

Comment: I'm not using variables here. This php array described in project configs but I'm currently working on OpenAPI 3 docs => writting a openapi.json

Comment: This is not an answer, it's a comment and also the syntax is wrong. `json_encode()` takes an `integer` of options (a bitmask) as second parameter, not a boolean. The boolean is for `json_decode` to tell PHP wether to transform the JSON to an associative array or to an object.